# How to get and set variable in notification?(Android)

Tags: java, android, notifications, firebase

I am using cloud service provider(FIREBASE) and i got stock in this process. 
1st. sending message on the app. will count the notification in the numMessages.
the code is like:

```
int numMessage:
```

then the setter:

```
message.setnumMessage(numMessages);
```

then the counter:

```
numMessages++
```

now on the structure of my firebase chat this will be the output,

```
name:test
numMessages:1
readCount:0
```

now what i want is when i click the Pending intent activity . the readCount will be changed for what ever value of the numMessages.
in that case when i click the notification the readCount must changed to 1 because the value of the numMessages is 1.

```
PendingIntent pIntent =
    PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class), 0);
pIntent.equals(readCount=numMessages);

if (numMessages > 0 && targetId == R.id.button) {
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setTicker("You Have " + numMessages + " message")
        .setContentTitle("test")
        .setContentText("")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_od_icon_24dp)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
    noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    noti.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
    noti.ledOnMS = LED_ON_MS;
    noti.ledOffMS = LED_OFF_MS;
    noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
    NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using this line: `pIntent.equals(readCount=numMessages);`?

Comment: i just tried it.  do you have suggestion sir?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, can you edit it and show us what you're trying to do. For example, First Notification should look like this, second should look like that, and so on, so the community can figure out what you really want to do.

Comment: ok thanks , i will edit it .

Comment: done @EricB. hope you can suggest idea or prove , tnx

Comment: It's much clear now, just a bit of confusion in the last part "when i click the notification the readCount must changed to 1 because the value of the numMessages is 1". Does this mean you want to update the value of the same notification from 0 to 1?

Comment: yes sir . like this sir. think that you are chatting with someone. if you send 5x . the numMessages will be equals to 5 if you look at firebase , then if you click the notification , the value of readCount will be equals to the value of numMessages. got it sir?

Comment: sir try to check this link . this is my firebase account , you will see the structure https://my-first-app-is.firebaseio.com/

Comment: Let's assume your numMessages is 2. If you click the notification it will open the pending intent and logically the notification should be cancelled once the MainActivity opens up, after that when another message comes then numMessages should be 3 and the readCount should be 2 right?

Comment: yes sir , you got it exactly ! the readCount will be equal to 2 , unless the user didn't click the notification for the readCount to make it 3

Comment: @nguoixanh's approach is correct, you should use it, it will solve your problem.

Comment: yeah i tried it earlier but it seems the code was wrong , urg

Comment: Post the code you tried.

Comment: @EricB. i tried the code under, but the setLatestEventValue has an error , i tried research but nothings happen , since it a receiver , the builder doesnt recognize it , because i just did create a notification buider in the mainActivity .

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
You want everytime receive notification, it change value of numMessages, and somewhere in your app, update value of numMessages to readCount ?
If I understand your problem, here are steps you can try:

A. Create Receiver to handle when receive notificaion

B. Get value of variable from Notification:

1. You can use static variable for numMessages and reference to it on other readCount.
2. Or, Using database or SharedPreference

And, Set value to Notification:

Similar to get value from Notification. Use static variable or database or SharedPreference

A little sample code:

MainActivity.class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
    public void onGenNoti(View v) {

        // Check readCount
        Variables.readCount = Variables.numMessages;

        PendingIntent pIntent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 0, new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class), 0);

            if (Variables.numMessages > 0) {
                Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTicker("You Have " + Variables.numMessages + " message")
                    .setContentTitle("test")
                    .setContentText("")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_od_icon_24dp)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
                noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                noti.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
                noti.ledARGB = Color.BLUE;
                noti.ledOnMS = LED_ON_MS;
                noti.ledOffMS = LED_OFF_MS;
                noti.flags = Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);
            }
    }
}
```

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Generate Noti"
        android:onClick="onGenNoti"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Variables.class

```
public class Variables {
    public static int numMessages;
    public static int readCount;
}
```

Receiver.class:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final Object ACTION = "MyNotification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION.equals(action)) {
            //do what you want here
            Variables.numMessages++;
            generateNotification(context,"MyNotification");
        }
    }

    private void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
          long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
          int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
          NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
          Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);
          String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
          // String subTitle = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
          String subTitle = "some text";
          Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
          notificationIntent.putExtra("content", message);
          PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, 0);
          notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

          notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, subTitle, intent);
          //To play the default sound with your notification:
          //notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
          notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
          notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
          notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
    }

}
```

And last, add these line inside application tag in Manifest

```
<receiver
            android:name="your.package.Receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="MyNotification" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: sir i improved my explanation. what do you think?same suggestion?

Comment: Ok, I think my understanding about your question is right, so, you can try my suggestion.

Comment: i think i tried you suggestion sir earlier , but i dont think the code are right , urgh. my problem, :/

Comment: wow , thanks! the setLatesEventInfo has an error. unknown expression type